# how to build dynamic query

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

Hi I have to query a record information of the customer. Based on the number of Order the customer submits it should retrieve the same.

Please find my query below
In the above code i am using the static value to get the same record.
I want to make it Dynamic. Please Advise.

I tried the Below logic it still returns me only one at a time.

```
 if(OrderNumbers!=null){
         String[] splits = OrderNumbers.split(',');
        String succMes = (splits.size() >1 ? 'Thank you for your order request.  Your Order Numbers are ' : 'Thank you for your order request.  Your Order Number is ');
        Set<String> orderIds = new Set<String>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i< splits.size(); i++){
            orderIds.add(splits[i]);
        }
        newOrders = [Select id,
                     Order_Contact__c,
                     OrderNumber,
                     Order_Contact_Phone__c,
                     Order_Contact_Email__c,
                     Type,
                     Rush_Order__c,
                     Type_Of_Order__c,
                     Training_Required__c,
                     Type_Of_Clock__c,
                     Number_of_Clock_Required__c,
                     Ship_to__c,Shipping_Attention__c,
                     Shipping_Attention_Email__c,
                     Shipping_Attention_Phone__c,
                     Shipping_Street__c,
                     Suite_Floor_Address_2__c,
                     Shipping_City__c,
                     Shipping_State__c,
                     Shipping_Postal_Code__c,
                     Shipping_Country__c,
                     Clock_Location_Restriction__c,
                     IP_Restricted__c,
                     Type_of_Clock_Requested__c,
                     Connection_Type__c,
                     Static_IP_Address__c,
                     Static_Subnet_Mask__c,
                     Static_Gateway_Adress__c,
                     DNS1__c,
                     DNS2__c,
                     Branch_Name__c,
                     Branch_number__c,
                     Associates_to_enter_time__c,
                     First_email_reminder_day__c,
                     Second_email_reminder_day__c,
                     PTA_First_email_Day__c,
                     PTA_Second_email_Day__c,
                     PTA_Escalation_email_Day__c,
                     StartTime_for_the_Last_shift_week_time__c,
                     PTA_First_email_Time__c,
                     PTA_Second_email_Time__c,
                     PTA_Escalation_email_Time__c,
                     First_shift_of_the_week_s_start_time__c,
                     Associates_to_enter_late_time__c,
                     i_How_Many_Weeks__c,
                     Last_day_of_your_pay_week__c,
                     Set_up_for_Group_Timesheet__c,
                     Clients_Branch_Name__c,
                     Clients_Branch_ID__c,
                     GT_How_do_they_need_to_enter_time__c,
                     GT_First_name_of_time_submitter__c,
                     GT_Last_name_of_time_submitter__c,
                     Submitter_s_email_address__c,
                     Submitter_First_reminder_day__c,
                     Submitter_Second_reminder_day__c,
                     Auto_approved_submitted_Group_Timesheet__c,
                     Over_Time_Rules__c,
                     Notes__c,
                     Customer_Name__c,
                     Business_Unit_Or_Accounting_number__c,
                     Site_ID_or_Branch_ID_Number__c,
                     Name_of_Clock_Location__c,
                     Site_Street_Address_1__c,
                     Site_Street_Address_2__c,
                     Site_City__c,
                     Site_State__c,
                     Site_ZIP__c,
                     Site_Country_if_not_USA__c,
                     Site_TimeZone__c,
                     Number_of_Employees__c,
                     Pay_Period__c,
                     First_Day_of_payroll_Week__c,
                     First_shift_of_the_week_s_start_day__c,
                     StartTime_for_the_Last_shift_of_the_week__c,
                     Third_Shift_employee_at_the_site__c,
                     OverTime_Rules__c,
                     State_OT_Rules__c,
                     Daily_OT_after_How_many_hours__c,
                     Weekly_OT_after_how_many_hours__c,
                     Does_the_7th_day_rule_apply__c,
                     Non_Standard_Notes__c,
                     Time_Tracking_Options__c,
                     Grace_Period_Before_Shift__c,
                     Grace_Period_After_Shift__c,
                     Meal_Break__c,
                     Length_of_the_meal_break__c,
                     Min_hours_worked_for_auto_meal_deduction__c,
                     California_Meal_Prompts__c,
                     Are_Departments_sent_in_Integration_file__c,
                     Special_Pay_Policies_or_Requests__c 
                     from Order where OrderNumber IN :orderIds];
```

Here is the code that defines the OrderNumbers

```
public without sharing class NewOrderSuccessController {

public List<Order> newOrders{get;set;}
//public List<OrderTraining__c> orderTrainings{get;set;}
public String accountId{get; set;}

public NewOrderSuccessController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

    String OrderNumbers = GetValueFromParam('OrderNumbers'); 
    accountId = '';
    if(OrderNumbers.contains(';'))
    {
        String[] splitNumbers = OrderNumbers.split(';');
        OrderNumbers = splitNumbers[0];
        String str1 = splitNumbers[1];            

       /* if(str1.contains('CID'))
        {
            String[] splitaccount = str1.split('=');
            accountId = splitaccount[1];
        } */       
    }

    if(OrderNumbers!=null){
         String[] splits = OrderNumbers.split(',');
        String succMes = (splits.size() >1 ? 'Thank you for your order request.  Your Order Numbers are ' : 'Thank you for your order request.  Your Order Number is ');
```

Comment: What is the content of `OrderNumbers` ?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn The content of the OrderNumbers is {00002928,00002929,00002930}

Comment: So if `OrderNumbers` is an array of Strings then your query could just be `WHERE OrderNumber IN :OrderNumbers`

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Yes I was trying that before. In VF page we have option where the customer will be allowed to order multiple clocks, When they submit there will be multiple separate order get created for no . of clock they selected. But the order number retrieved only one

Comment: Check your debug logs...how many records does it say its retreiving?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn the Log says the sql returns 0 records

Comment: Ok, if you can add `System.debug(JSON.serialize(orderIds));` prior to doing your query, whats the output of that?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn It is showing numm as Similar to this 18:59:03:004 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|[""]  and another is 18:59:03:004 METHOD_ENTRY [9]|System.JSON.serialize(Object)

Comment: Ok, so that indicates that `orderIds` is empty thus your query is looking for no orders which then points to something being awry with your `OrderNumbers` variable. Might be worth updating your question to show the definition of `OrderNumbers`

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I have updated my question with the OrderNumber Defenition

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I have tried debugging using the Json and got this result  19:27:20:003 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|["00002922"," 00002923"," 00002924"," 00002925"," 00002926"]

Comment: @PhilHawthorn And when I did system debug to check the size of the query returned is 19:32:46:108 USER_DEBUG [99]|DEBUG|Total orders returned1

Comment: Ok, I see the issue - its subtle, but you have spaces in front of your values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From information supplied in comments, it your OrderNumbers array is:

`["00002922"," 00002923"," 00002924"," 00002925"," 00002926"]`

Therefore, when converting that to your Set:

```
    Set<String> orderIds = new Set<String>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i< splits.size(); i++){
        orderIds.add(splits[i]);
    }
```

It is also including the spaces meaning that only the first item in the array is a valid Order Number. So, you can change your code to:

```
    Set<String> orderIds = new Set<String>();
    for(String orderNo : OrderNumbers){
        orderIds.add(orderNo.replaceAll(' ', ''));
    }
```

And at least valid Order Numbers will be queried for.

Comment: That fixed the issue and Provides me the solution. Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic SOQL,please refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) .Also please check if the orderIds still contains value after split.

```
for(Integer i = 0; i< splits.size(); i++){
            orderIds.add(splits[i]);
}

if(orderIds.size()>0){
String sql ='Select id,
                         Order_Contact__c,
                         OrderNumber,
                         Order_Contact_Phone__c,
                         Order_Contact_Email__c,
                         Type,
                         Rush_Order__c,
                         Type_Of_Order__c,
                         Training_Required__c,
                         Type_Of_Clock__c,
                         Number_of_Clock_Required__c,
                         Ship_to__c,Shipping_Attention__c,
                         Shipping_Attention_Email__c,
                         Shipping_Attention_Phone__c,
                         Shipping_Street__c,
                         Suite_Floor_Address_2__c,
                         Shipping_City__c,
                         Shipping_State__c,
                         Shipping_Postal_Code__c,
                         Shipping_Country__c,
                         Clock_Location_Restriction__c,
                         IP_Restricted__c,
                         Type_of_Clock_Requested__c,
                         Connection_Type__c,
                         Static_IP_Address__c,
                         Static_Subnet_Mask__c,
                         Static_Gateway_Adress__c,
                         DNS1__c,
                         DNS2__c,
                         Branch_Name__c,
                         Branch_number__c,
                         Associates_to_enter_time__c,
                         First_email_reminder_day__c,
                         Second_email_reminder_day__c,
                         PTA_First_email_Day__c,
                         PTA_Second_email_Day__c,
                         PTA_Escalation_email_Day__c,
                         StartTime_for_the_Last_shift_week_time__c,
                         PTA_First_email_Time__c,
                         PTA_Second_email_Time__c,
                         PTA_Escalation_email_Time__c,
                         First_shift_of_the_week_s_start_time__c,
                         Associates_to_enter_late_time__c,
                         i_How_Many_Weeks__c,
                         Last_day_of_your_pay_week__c,
                         Set_up_for_Group_Timesheet__c,
                         Clients_Branch_Name__c,
                         Clients_Branch_ID__c,
                         GT_How_do_they_need_to_enter_time__c,
                         GT_First_name_of_time_submitter__c,
                         GT_Last_name_of_time_submitter__c,
                         Submitter_s_email_address__c,
                         Submitter_First_reminder_day__c,
                         Submitter_Second_reminder_day__c,
                         Auto_approved_submitted_Group_Timesheet__c,
                         Over_Time_Rules__c,
                         Notes__c,
                         Customer_Name__c,
                         Business_Unit_Or_Accounting_number__c,
                         Site_ID_or_Branch_ID_Number__c,
                         Name_of_Clock_Location__c,
                         Site_Street_Address_1__c,
                         Site_Street_Address_2__c,
                         Site_City__c,
                         Site_State__c,
                         Site_ZIP__c,
                         Site_Country_if_not_USA__c,
                         Site_TimeZone__c,
                         Number_of_Employees__c,
                         Pay_Period__c,
                         First_Day_of_payroll_Week__c,
                         First_shift_of_the_week_s_start_day__c,
                         StartTime_for_the_Last_shift_of_the_week__c,
                         Third_Shift_employee_at_the_site__c,
                         OverTime_Rules__c,
                         State_OT_Rules__c,
                         Daily_OT_after_How_many_hours__c,
                         Weekly_OT_after_how_many_hours__c,
                         Does_the_7th_day_rule_apply__c,
                         Non_Standard_Notes__c,
                         Time_Tracking_Options__c,
                         Grace_Period_Before_Shift__c,
                         Grace_Period_After_Shift__c,
                         Meal_Break__c,
                         Length_of_the_meal_break__c,
                         Min_hours_worked_for_auto_meal_deduction__c,
                         California_Meal_Prompts__c,
                         Are_Departments_sent_in_Integration_file__c,
                         Special_Pay_Policies_or_Requests__c 
                         from Order where OrderNumber IN :orderIds';
    List<Order> newOrders= Database.query(string);

}
```

Comment: I think the question is possibly misleading, I think the OP is trying to retrieve multiple rows of data rather than making his query Dynamic in the way that you're thinking

Comment: @unidha the query returned null as it did not retrieve any record from Order Object